# solve block form objective-c to swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I have a trouble problem on block, on objective-c it works well, but I couldn't translate to swift 3,

in objective-c case

```
typedef void (^PanCellToDeleteBlock)(NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath);

@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (copy , nonatomic) PanCellToDeleteBlock panCellToDeleteBlock;
```

in swift 3 case

```
public typealias PanCellToDeleteBlock = (_ cell:NSIndexPath) -> Void

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

let panCellToDeleteBlock:PanCellToDeleteBlock? = nil
```

it looks no swift.....

here is when I use it in same class

in objective-c case

```
if (_panCellToDeleteBlock) {
    _panCellToDeleteBlock(_cellIndexPath);
}
```

in swift case, everything looks wrong

```
if (self.panCellToDeleteBlock != nil) {
    self.panCellToDeleteBlock(self.cellIndexPath)
}
```

here is must crazy part, this is in viweController
OC case

```
cell.panCellToDeleteBlock = ^(NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath){
    [weakSelf.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
    [weakSelf.collectionView reloadData];
};
```

swift part I already can't do anything ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift 3 equivalents are

```
public typealias PanCellToDeleteBlock = (IndexPath) -> Void

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var panCellToDeleteBlock : PanCellToDeleteBlock?
```

---

```
self.panCellToDeleteBlock?(self.cellIndexPath)
```

---

```
cell.panCellToDeleteBlock = { [weak self] indexPath in
    self?.dataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
public typealias PanCellToDeleteBlock = (_ indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void

cell.panCellToDeleteBlock: PanCellToDeleteBlock = { [weak self] indexPath in
    self?.dataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```